# Show each month as a column in a table in PowerBI

Tags: datatable, powerbi

I want to show in a table each month of ExaminationDate rather than just the year and month. For example, currently I have ExaminationDate in Field with Year and Month selected which shows:

```
Year        Month
2021        January
2021        Febuary
2021        March
```

But how would I get it to display thusly:

```
Year       January    February     March    etc
2021        value
2021
2021
```

Comment: [Pivot columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns).

Comment: Any way of doing this on the desktop version? Doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: PowerBi desktop has the same function `pivot column`, did you try it before?

Comment: Where is the option to Pivot Column? Can I do this from the report section?